# gtkSwitch in pygtk 2 on windows

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3, gtk2

I'm creating a python program to switch some hardware devices on and off. The program has to run on windows. I would really like to use the [gtkSwitch widget](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkSwitch.html) that was created in gtk 3.0, because then it is immediately obvious that you want a device to be switched on or off, but unfortunately gtk3 has not been properly ported to windows for python. So is there any way to use the gtkswitch that comes with gtk 3.0 without having to write the program in gtk3, or does anyone know of a way to use python bindings for gtk 3.0 on windows?

thanks a lot!

Dirk Boonzajer

Answer (score -1):

please see my code

https://gist.github.com/shellexy/2f86cfa4a0448f7125e8

I use gtk.ToggleButton to simulation gtk.Switch button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLvq7.png

gtkswitchbutton.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
    # vim:set shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 expandtab textwidth=79:
    '''GtkSwitch for PyGtk2
    @author: Shellexy 
    @license: LGPLv3+
    @see: 
    '''

    import gtk, gobject

    try: import i18n
    except: from gettext import gettext as _


    class SwitchButton(gtk.Table):
        __gtype_name__ = 'SwitchButton'
        __gsignals__ = {
            'toggled': (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, None, ()),
        }
        def __init__(self):
            gtk.Table.__init__(self)
            self.label = _("ON\tOFF")
            self.tbutton = gtk.ToggleButton()
            self.tbutton.set_label(self.label)
            self.cbutton = gtk.Button()
            self.cbutton.set_sensitive(True)
            self.cbutton.set_can_focus(False)
            self.cbutton.set_can_default(False)
            self.attach(self.cbutton, 0, 2, 0, 1)
            self.attach(self.tbutton, 0, 4, 0, 1)
            self.tbutton.connect('toggled', self.do_switch)
            self.cbutton.connect('clicked', lambda *args: self.clicked)
            #self.connect('realize', self.do_switch)
            self.set_active(False)
            self.show_all()
            pass

        def toggled(self, *args):
            return self.clicked()

        def clicked(self, *args):
            return self.tbutton.clicked()

        def set_inconsistent(self, setting):
            return self.tbutton(setting)

        def set_active(self, is_active):
            return gobject.idle_add(self.tbutton.set_active, not is_active)

        def get_active(self):
            return not self.tbutton.get_active()

        def do_switch(self, *args):
            return gobject.idle_add(self._do_switch, *args)

        def _do_switch(self, *args):
            t = self
            tb = self.tbutton
            b = self.cbutton
            l = tb.get_child()
            l.set_justify(gtk.JUSTIFY_FILL)
            bs = tb.get_style().copy()
            ls = l.get_style().copy()
            bs.bg[gtk.STATE_NORMAL] = ls.bg[gtk.STATE_SELECTED]
            ls.fg[gtk.STATE_NORMAL] = ls.text[gtk.STATE_SELECTED]       
            if self.get_children():
                t.remove(b); t.remove(tb)
                pass
            if self.get_active():
                t.attach(b, 2, 4, 0, 1) ; t.attach(tb, 0, 4, 0, 1)
                bs.bg[gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT] = ls.bg[gtk.STATE_SELECTED]
                ls.fg[gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT] = ls.text[gtk.STATE_SELECTED]
                pass
            else:
                t.attach(b, 0, 2, 0, 1) ; t.attach(tb, 0, 4, 0, 1)
                bs.bg[gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT] = ls.bg[gtk.STATE_INSENSITIVE]
                ls.fg[gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT] = ls.text[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
                pass
            tb.set_style(bs)
            l.set_style(ls)
            tb.do_focus(tb, 1)
            self.emit('toggled')
            pass


    def main():
        window = gtk.Window()
        window.set_title('PyGtk2 SwitchButton')
        options = [
                ['Connect: ', False],
                ['Auto Connect: ', True],
                ['Auto Proxy: ', True],
        ]
        vbox = gtk.VBox()
        vbox.set_spacing(5)
        def foo(*args):
            print args
        for k, v in options:
            s = SwitchButton()
            s.set_active(v)
            s.connect('toggled', foo, k)
            hbox = gtk.HBox()
            label = gtk.Label(k)
            label.set_alignment(0, 0.5)
            hbox.pack_start(label, 1, 1, 0)
            hbox.pack_start(s, 0, 0, 0)
            vbox.pack_start(hbox, 0, 0, 0)
            pass
        window.add(vbox)
        window.show_all()
        window.connect('destroy', lambda *args: gtk.main_quit())
        gtk.main()
        pass

    if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: and, there is pygtk3 for windows download https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/PyGObject#Binaries , but it is so bulky.